# How to include state/props in useEffect without it becoming a trigger?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The example below will throw a warning that `someState` should be included in the dependency array of the `useEffect`, however I do not wish for changes to `someState` to trigger the `useEffect` to run.

So, how do I make sure that the function runs on updates to `someTrigger` while running with an updated version of `someState`?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function someFunction() {
  const [someTrigger, setSomeTrigger] = useState(null)
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    async function postSomething() {
      const response = await fetch('somePath',
         method: 'POST',
         body: JSON.stringify(someState),
      })
      ...
    } 
    postSomething()
  } [someTrigger])

  return <SomeComponent />
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just add `someState` as dep? Since you're not changing it inside the effect this won't generate a loop

Comment: In this example, you're right, but in my actual use case I cannot. I need the trigger to be in control of the runtime.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Only trigger the effect when `someTrigger` changes?

Comment: But since `someState` is a piece of local state it is expected to change. And the effect should run again to keep synchronicity. If `someState` never changes you could declare it outside your component

Comment: Yes. I only want the effect to run when `someTrigger` changes, not when `someState` does.

Comment: But what if `someState` changes? What is the expected behavior for that? The effect should run only once?

Comment: Exactly. Is there any way I can keep its synchronicity, without running `postSomething()` on every update to `someState`.

It shouldn't just run once, but every time `someTrigger` updates.

Comment: You could use https://stackoverflow.com/a/55854902/2295549, https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies, https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to `postSomething` in response to some event, it is better to just call it the event handler directly, instead of going through an effect:

```
<SomeComponent onEvent={() => postSomething() } />
```

If for some reason that doesn't work for you and you need an effect, you can just ignore the warning.